# search for a string between repetitive tags in a txt file

Tags: perl

Need some help with respect to search for a string between repetitive tags
I have a text file with following format repeating many times within a file

========== File Name: fixed_am_7bitLI_HE10.txt Test Case: Test_Case_1 START ==========

Block 1
TC ID OK

Block 2
Input section OK
data section OK

Block 3
Input section OK
data section OK

Block 4
Input section OK
data section OK

========== File Name: fixed_am_7bitLI_HE10.txt Test Case: Test_Case_2 START ========

Block 1
TC ID OK

Block 2
Input section OK

- line mismatch:
  output line: "Buffer allocated from pool: MIF_CTRL_POOL, buffer_id: 1, size (words): 4"
  reference line: "pdcp_pdu_delete_count = 0, reset_cip_rdy = 1"
- line mismatch:
  output line: "pdcp_pdu_delete_count = 0, reset_cip_rdy = 1"
  reference line: "-- MIF CTRL output: --------------------------------------------------------------------------------"
- line mismatch:
  output line: "-- MIF CTRL output: --------------------------------------------------------------------------------"
  reference line: "mif_ctrl_rlc_am_um_reset_reestablish_ind_t.rlc_reset_reestablish_ind = 3 (0x0003)"
- line mismatch:
  output line: "mif_ctrl_rlc_am_um_reset_reestablish_ind_t.rlc_reset_reestablish_ind = 3 (0x0003)"
  reference line: "Buffer released from pool: MIF_CTRL_POOL, buffer_id 0, size (words) 6 (used 5)"
- line count mismatch:
  last output line: "mif_ctrl_rlc_am_um_reset_reestablish_ind_t.rlc_reset_reestablish_ind = 3 (0x0003)" 
  last reference line: "Buffer released from pool: MIF_CTRL_POOL, buffer_id 0, size (words) 6 (used 5)"

data section DIFFERS

Block 3
Input section OK
data section OK

Block 4
Input section OK
data section OK

========== File Name: fixed_am_7bitLI_HE10.txt Test Case: Test_Case_3 START ========

Block 1
TC ID OK

Block 2
Input section OK
data section OK

Block 3
Input section OK
data section OK

Block 4
Input section OK
data section OK

**I need to find if anything other than 'OK' exists between the Start tags and if yes i have to mark the particular block as failed

for example if i find any other than OK between Test Case: Test_Case_1 START and Test Case: Test_Case_2 START i have to mark Test Case: Test_Case_1 as failed

**UPDATED**
Expected Output in somewhat this format

File Name: fixed_am_7bitLI_HE10.txt Test Case: Test_Case_1 Status: PASS 
(if there is no string as 'DIFFERS' between tags (==)

File Name: fixed_am_7bitLI_HE10.txt Test Case: Test_Case_2 Status: FAILED 
(if there is string 'DIFFERS' between tags (==)

**UPDATE -2**

If in case Test Case fails

File Name: fixed_am_7bitLI_HE10.txt Test Case: Test_Case_2 Status: FAILED

Section of block differing is:

Block 2

Input section OK

- line mismatch:
  output line: "Buffer allocated from pool: MIF_CTRL_POOL, buffer_id: 1, size (words): 4"
  reference line: "pdcp_pdu_delete_count = 0, reset_cip_rdy = 1"
- line mismatch:
  output line: "pdcp_pdu_delete_count = 0, reset_cip_rdy = 1"
  reference line: "-- MIF CTRL output: --------------------------------------------------------------------------------"
- line mismatch:
  output line: "-- MIF CTRL output: --------------------------------------------------------------------------------"
  reference line: "mif_ctrl_rlc_am_um_reset_reestablish_ind_t.rlc_reset_reestablish_ind = 3 (0x0003)"
- line mismatch:
  output line: "mif_ctrl_rlc_am_um_reset_reestablish_ind_t.rlc_reset_reestablish_ind = 3 (0x0003)"
  reference line: "Buffer released from pool: MIF_CTRL_POOL, buffer_id 0, size (words) 6 (used 5)"
- line count mismatch:
  last output line: "mif_ctrl_rlc_am_um_reset_reestablish_ind_t.rlc_reset_reestablish_ind = 3 (0x0003)" 
  last reference line: "Buffer released from pool: MIF_CTRL_POOL, buffer_id 0, size (words) 6 (used 5)"

data section DIFFERS

Comment: Please, show us what you have tried.

Comment: Also, elaborate what you mean by "mark". Make changes to the file? Just print which tests failed to stdout?

Comment: your spec of what is a "fail" is not complete.  Is "input sections not found" count as a fail or not?  It isn't clear where your "OK" tags appear.  I started writing a short script but stopped as it isn't at all clear what you want to achieve

Answer (score 0):

Wild guess:

```
while(<>) {print '**FAIL**' unless /TC ID OK/;  print $_; }
```

But really, you should specify your requirements.

Comment: i have updated my question hope its clear now; i have tried similar what you have mentioned and also Adrian; but what i need is complete list from the input file (mentioned above)
Something like
File: <file Name> Test Case: <Test Case No> Status: PASS (if the data between the **START** tags doesnt contain 'DIFFERS')
File: <file Name> Test Case: <Test Case No> Status: FAILED (if the data between the **START** tags contain 'DIFFERS'(atleast once))

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something quirky along the lines of the following:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;

my ($failed, $file, $test);
while (<>)
{
        chomp;
        next if /^$/;
        if (/^=/)
        {
                print "$file $test Status: $failed\n" if $failed;
                ($file, $test) = ($_ =~ /(File Name:\s+\S+).+\b(Test Case: Test_Case_\d+)\b/);
                $failed = 'PASSED';
                next;
        };
        $failed = 'FAILED' if /\bDIFFERS\b/g;
}
print "$file $test Status: $failed\n";
```

### Data

```
$ cat testdata
========== File Name: fixed_am_7bitLI_HE10.txt Test Case: Test_Case_1 START ==========

Block 1 TC ID OK

Block 2 Input section OK data section OK

Block 3 Input section OK data section OK

Block 4 Input section OK data section OK

========== File Name: fixed_am_7bitLI_HE10.txt Test Case: Test_Case_2 START ========

Block 1 TC ID OK

Block 2 Input section OK data section DIFFERS

Block 3 Input section OK data section OK

Block 4 Input section OK data section OK
```

### Invocation

```
$ ./t.pl < testdata
File Name: fixed_am_7bitLI_HE10.txt Test Case: Test_Case_1 Status: PASSED
File Name: fixed_am_7bitLI_HE10.txt Test Case: Test_Case_2 Status: FAILED
```

Comment: Sorry for not a clear requirement; i have updated the question; i hope i am clear engough this time

Comment: @Ganga I might need new glasses but I don't see any change in your question?

Comment: I updated it now; just got into discussion in the middle of updates :)

Comment: Actually i had tried something similar but it returned status for only the last occurrence of Test Case 1 START; but not for all the occurrences from the beginning of the file :(

Comment: @Ganga It's still as unclear as before. Please give example(s) of cases that are required to be "marked" failed. Do you need to have at least one `OK` per `Block`-line to have the whole test case pass (in which case `Input section OK data section foobar not found` would not "mark" the test case as failed)? You didn't answer my question above regarding what exactly you mean by "mark" either

Comment: @Adrain: I need to find for string 'DIFFERS'(atleast one occurence) between the blocks(which has tag **START**) if yes then have to set the the test case id (that can be found in the First occurrence of tag) has Failed else i have to mark the test case id (found in the first occurrence of the tag) has Pass

Comment: @Adrain: I have further updated the requirement as; please refer to **UPDATED** section above

Comment: @Ganga I have updated my answer, it could be done more compact with a multiline match for `DIFFER` but since I am still not 100% certain about your specification I kept the skeleton I had before.

Comment: @Adrain: Thanks it works fine except the negative condition testdata file cant find the tag ===

Comment: @Ganga I don't understand...? My name spells Adrian, btw ;-)

Comment: Please give a sample output in your question, which is way easier to understand than trying to explain it verbally. Also, please mark all output in code blocks as explained [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/22189) - it is as simple as highlighting the lines in question and using the curly brackets of the editor or hitting CTRL-K on your keyboard.

Comment: You did not format your question as I asked you to, this is impossible to read and people would have to keep guessing what you are trying to accomplish ...